# <input> not able to be referred to by $_POST in PHP

Tags: php, input

I am trying to have two input boxes, and a button which will update them in a database. I have deletion, which works, adding new rows, and other things, yet this refuses to work:

```
    echo '<form action="index.php" method="post"><input placeholder="Enter a title here" type = "Text" name = "Title_input" value = "'.${notes.$loc."titles"}.'" style = "top:0px;left:230px;right:0px;height:30px;position:absolute;">';
echo '<textarea placeholder="Make note of something here!" cols="94" rows="20" name="Text_input" style="top:40px;left:230px;position:absolute;right:50px;">'.${notes.$loc."notes"}.'</textarea>';
```

Which prints the text boxes out to the page. I also have

```
 <form action="index.php" method = "post"><input type="Submit" name="Update" value="Update" style="right:0px;bottom:0px;height:50px;width:200px;position:inherit">
```

(It has the closing tags and everything after another block of code)

However when I run:

```
if (isset($_POST['Update']) && isset($_POST['Title_input']) && isset($_POST['Text_input'])) {
echo $_POST['Title_input'];
  } else {
echo "Failed";
  }
```

It echoes 'Failed'. I cannot see any issue, as the text areas would have been outputted so should be set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the input fields in the same form as the update button.

Comment: Indeed, for the sake of clarity on OP's part:  You currently have two forms on there.  Submitting one form will not bring in the contents of a different form.  Consolidate them, and your answer you shall find.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I just changed it over and now it works perfectly.